# In R Shiny , how to create multiples `outputs$...` on server function

Tags: r, shiny

I have this vector: `vec<-c(2,13,56,8,10,11,19)`

The output that I need should be like this:

```
        server <- function(input, output, session) {

vec<-c(2,13,56,8,10,11,19)

    output$report_2 <- renderUI({
...    
x <- 2
    })

    output$report_13 <- renderUI({
...    
x <- 13
    })

    output$report_56 <- renderUI({
...
x <- 56   
    })

    output$report_8 <- renderUI({
...
x <- 8  
    })

output$report_10 <- renderUI({
    ...
    x <- 10  
        })

output$report_11 <- renderUI({
    ...
    x <- 11  
        })

output$report_19 <- renderUI({
    ...
    x <- 19  
        })
    
    
        }
```

But I need to to this using `map`, and maybe `glue`. But I cant

In other words for each **k** number I need to create a function like this, and make this working in shiny:

```
output$report_k <- renderUI({
...    
x <- k
    })
```

Any help?

Many thanks

Comment: Use `[[` instead of `$` i.e. `k <- 2; output[[paste0("report_", k)]] <- renderUI{{..`.  If it needs to be `map` `output[paste0('report_', vec)] <- map(vec, ~ renderUI({x <- .x}))`

Comment: Consider using [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

Comment: What does the `renderUI()` print? In other words, what goes into the corresponding `uiOutput()`? knowing what the [...] represent in your code will help give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before modules we would wrap `textOutput` and `output[[...]] <- renderSomething` in an `lapply`:

```
library(shiny)

vec <- c(2,13,56,8,10,11,19)
 
shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  
  lapply(vec, function(x) textOutput(paste0("report_", x)))
  
), 

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  lapply(vec, function(x){
    output[[paste0("report_", x)]] <- 
      renderText({
        x
      })
  })
  
})
```

The above dashboard is the short version of:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  
  textOutput("report_2"),
  textOutput("report_13"),
  textOutput("report_56"),
  textOutput("report_8"),
  textOutput("report_10"),
  textOutput("report_11"),
  textOutput("report_19"),
  
  ), 
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  vec<-c(2,13,56,8,10,11,19)
  
  output$report_2 <- renderText({
    2
  })
  
  output$report_13 <- renderText({
    13
  })
  
  output$report_56 <- renderText({
    56   
  })
  
  output$report_8 <- renderText({
    8  
  })
  
  output$report_10 <- renderText({
    10  
  })
  
  output$report_11 <- renderText({
    11  
  })
  
  output$report_19 <- renderText({
    19  
  })
  
})
```

With modules we can create a module and call it with `lapply`. I'd say this is the recommended way.

```
library(shiny)

myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    textOutput(NS(id, "text"))
  )
}

myModuleServer <- function(id, val) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$text <- renderText({
      val
    })
  })
}

vec <- c(2,13,56,8,10,11,19)

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  
  lapply(vec, FUN = function(x) myModuleUI(paste0("report_", x)))
  
), 

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  lapply(vec, FUN = function(x) {
    myModuleServer(id = paste0("report_", x),
                   val = x)
    })
  
})
```

Comment: 's thanks! One question: in my case is this the best practice to create all of these `output$…`?

Comment: @Laura: I now added some example code how to do it with shiny modules. I'd say that this is probably best practice.